# Newsletter is not going to subscriber in magento2

Tags: magento2, cron, newsletter, magento-2.1.3

well there is an issue with newsletter in magento 2.is i have created newsletter template for subscriber but when i set a date and time to it.it was still not going to my subscribers.apart from this Transnational Emails are going perfectly only newsletter email are not going.also time is scheduling 4 hours latter while setting newsletter queue timings
[image].

Comment: any suggestions for the same?

Comment: any reply for the same please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

1. Choose correct timezone to solve timing issue as follow.

   > Stores-> Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale Options ->
   >   Timezone
2. You have to set Cronjob to send newsletter automatically on scheduled time. or you can manually run this command to run cron manually:

   > php bin/magento cron:run

For more details please visit below link:

[How to Setup Cron Job Magento 2 - Schedule Tasks](https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/cat/magento-2-email-newsletter/)

**Note**: I had to install SMTP extension (https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/) to send emails from my localhost.